# Só é possível escrever código com bugs ou vulnerabilidades em C?

Tags: c, segurança, xss

Quem é programador e experiente sabe de uma verdade implícita: C é praticamente a linguagem dos deuses. C corresponde a pelo menos 98% do software que roda em todos os computadores e graças a seu baixo nível permite coisas incríveis.

Entretanto, graças a isso C também é conhecido por ser uma linguagem em que é realmente difícil escrever código seguro. Um exemplo é o velho conhecido [Buffer Overflow](http://www.cic.unb.br/~rezende/trabs/buffer_overflow.htm). E para os pouco experientes que não entendem disso, leiam [este artigo em inglês explicando detalhadamente a vulnerabilidade HeartBleed do OpenSSL](http://blog.existentialize.com/diagnosis-of-the-openssl-heartbleed-bug.html) e vocês terão uma ideia do perigo que um código em C relaxado cria.

Mas eu só vejo análises de segurança e coisas do tipo para o C sendo que eu sei que existem problemas de segurança relacionados a outras linguagens. Um caso que me intrigou foram casos com Java (da qual eu não tenho links pra espeficar)
. Pelo que eu li os exploits que exploram as vulnerabilidades no JRE são puro Java! Isso dá a entender que nessa linguagem é possível ter um código com brechas. Mas como isso é possível? Enquanto que em C você pode se referir ao elemento no index 20 num array de comprimento 10, Java lança uma exceção para qualquer coisa!

Também conheço problemas relacionados a Javascript. Esses me intrigam mais ainda: Javascript está totalmente preso ao escopo do navegador e da página em sí. Como é possível escrever um código malicioso nessa linguagem?

Em suma, a pergunta é: Só é possível escrever código com bugs em C ou em outras linguagens isso também é possível?

**Edit:**

Como destacado pelo Maniero, a palavra "bug" não parece adequada para a pergunta já que na realidade eu estou me referindo a vulnerabilidades (embora *bugs* exploráveis também caibam no escopo).

Comment: Eu mudaria algumas coisas na pergunta. Bugs e vulnerabilidades são coisas diferentes. Do jeito que está escrito demora para entender o que é a pergunta. E ainda dá a impressão de ser algo tendencioso contra o C e só a leitura cuidadosa faz perceber que não é bem isto. E ainda não há tantos softwares assim que são feitos em C. Há muitos, mas não tantos. Mesmo se somar aqueles feitos em C++ que acho que hoje superam os desenvolvidos em C. Mas este é um número chutado também.

Comment: Não vou responder porque não achei uma forma sem dar pura opinião. Resumindo C realmente facilita algumas vulnerabilidades que muitas outras linguagens dificultam embora existam ferramentas e técnicas para evitá-las. Java está sempre entre os maiores vetores de vulnerabilidades em computadores, só são outros tipos. Certos problemas de segurança não podem ser resolvidos com uma máquina virtual e certas restrições na linguagem. Por outro lado muita coisa que roda com o Java é escrito em C++ e pode até delegar parte da culpa para ele, mas o resultado e o culpado no final das contas é o mesmo.

Comment: Javascript rodando em um *browser* tem problemas bem menores mas há riscos. Os problema são menores por causa do *browser* que limita o acesso ao computador. Claro que linguagens mais modernas e mais restritivas ajudam a evitar vulnerabilidades mas há tantas formas possíveis que não dá para garantir segurança em tecnologia alguma. Nem aplicativos *mobile* nessas *stores* estão livres disto, eles apenas passam por um processo que ajuda evitar publicação com vulnerabilidades. Enfim, o assunto é complexo e também não vou conseguir resumir em comentários. Torço para que alguém responda legal.

Comment: @Maniero Bugs e vulnerabilidades são coisas diferentes? Pelo que ando lendo os dois termos são em parte intercambiáveis, apesar de bug ser representado como um comportamento estranho no programa e vulnerabilidade uma falha na lógica do programa que permite execução de código arbitrário ou exploração maliciosa. Mas acho que os dois termos estão na realidade bem próximos. Não é possível usar um bug para fins maliciosos?

Comment: @Maniiero Sim, o fator "segurança" em C é uma discussão a parte e que inclusive envolve opinião pessoal. Mas, tentando ser o mais imparcial o possível, eu digo que C é assim "frágil" justamente porque ele é praticamente um "Assembly" legível. Ele é uma linguagem crua e sem recursos vistos em linguagens de alto nível justamente porque ele foi feito para trabalhar com programação no nível mais baixo o possível com bons recursos. E por essas e outras que ele é tão rápido. Eu acho que nunca conseguiriam adicionar uma nova feature em C sem um overhead considerável.

Comment: @Maniero E eu digo que C é pelo menos 98% do software rodando nos nossos computadores porque C é uma linguagem fundamental. É, inclusive, através dele que linguanges de alto nível que tanto aceleram nossa produtividade são implementadas! Inclusive a JVM e o CLR (do .NET) são escritos em C/C++! E os interpretadores de Python, Ruby e etc também são implementados em C.

Comment: Você anda lendo em lugares ruins ou interpretando errado. Você mesmo acabou de dizer que são coisas diferentes na sua definição. É só ler com cuidado o que que escreveu. Nem todo bug é uma vulnerabilidade e uma vulnerabilidade pode ocorrer por outros meios. Um programa resultar em "2" e deveria resultar em "3" é um bug. Que código malicioso pode ser executado por causa disto? A questão do C é bem mais complexa que isto, por isso eu preferi não responder. Para não ficar no achismo EU teria que escrever um capítulo de livro. Não estou dizendo que não possa ser respondido objetivamente por outro.

Comment: Então acho que é adequada uma edição no título da pergunta.

Comment: C é uma coisa C++ é outra. C++ é menos propenso a bugs e vulnerabilidades que C, pelo menos se usar da maneira recomendada. E se entrar nas diversas camadas de um software fica mais complicado. Eu ainda tenho outra visão sobre a utilização tão intensa de C e não **acho** que chegue a 98% mesmo se somar C++. Como não tenho dados não posso afirmar.

Comment: Na realidade acho que seria mais adequado dizer "família de linguagens C-like" ou "C/C++". Mas no geral especificar C também especifica C++.

Comment: @Sid bug é um problema "criado" pelo programador, vulnerabilidade se refere a algo que o programador não teve culpa.

Comment: Programar corretamente não exige que você seja um gênio: [Put Yourself Out There: The Myth of the Genius Programmer](http://joshldavis.com/2014/06/13/put-yourself-out-there/)

Comment: Eu não li os comentários, então posso estar repetindo o que alguém falou. Mas sim é possivel escrever código vulneravel com outras linguagens (até mesmo linguagens interpretadas). As pessoas ficam presas sempre a Buffer overflow, sendo que vulnerabilidades de corrupção de memória podem ser exploradas de outras formas. Mas também é possivel gerar buffer overflow em java, em alguns senários mais específicos. Quando eu tiver em casa, eu formularei uma resposta mais completa que lhe dará um norte melhor sobre isso!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A razão que você ouve bastante sobre erros usando C é porque é uma linguagem *extremamente* popular, usada em muitos sistemas e bibliotecas importantes em que alguns erros fáceis de cometor podem ser convertidos em vulnerabilidades (acesso a vetor out of bounds, "dangling pointers", etc).

Dito isso, uma vulnerabilidade é qualquer coisa que um adversário possa usar contra o seu sistema, o que é algo extremamente amplo e que pode ocorer com qualquer sistema independente de qual linguagem for usada em sua implementação.

Um exemplo simples que podemos são vulnerabilidades de injeção de código, como o SQL injection. Por exemplo, suponha que eu tenha uma pagina web em que o usuário digita o nome de um país e o sistema responde com o número de gols que esse pais marcou na copa do mundo. Se meus dados estiverem num banco relacional eu vou ter que preparar uma pergunta para o banco similar à seguinte:

```
 pergunta = "SELECT gols FROM tabela_copa WHERE pais='Brasil';"
 gols = bandoDeDados.executar(pergunta)
```

A maneira ingênua de passar o país escolhido pelo usuário é usar concatenação ou interpolação de strings:

```
pais = entrada_do_usuario()
pergunta = "SELECT gols FROM tabela_copa WHERE pais='" + pais + "';"
gols = bandoDeDados.executar(pergunta)
```

Agora, o que ocorre se o usuário digitar o seguinte "país" no campo de busca?

```
'; DROP TABLE tabela_copa
```

O comando gerado vai ser

```
SELECT gols FROM tabela_copa WHERE pais='';
DROP TABLE tabela_copa;
```

E vamos deletar todos os nossos dados do banco. Basicamente, nós demos uma brecha para que o usuário executasse SQL em nosso banco de dados **em nosso nome** e o banco de dados, que confia em nós, executou os comandos cegamente.

A execução de código SQL não é uma vulnerabilidade tão direta como um defeito de buffer overflow mas ainda assim é uma forma de escalação de privilégios e execução remota de código. Problemas similares de injeção de código também são muito comuns em outros contextos:

- Manuseios incorreto de dados de usuário em páginas HTML pode levar vulnerabilidades XSS (cross site scripting).
- Servidores avaliando dados do código do usuário como código. Por exemplo, em PHP isso pode ocorrer em [expressões regulares com o modificador /e](http://www.secalert.net/2013/12/13/ebay-remote-code-execution/)
- [Phreaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phreaking), uma técnica envolvendo uma série de assobios precisos que os primeiros Hackers usavam para falar de graça no orelhão.

Bem, alguem pode chagar agora e dizer que esses bugs são culpa do programador e não da linguagem. Mas é verdade? Já cansei de ouvir gente usando esse mesmo argumento para defender C ("se você nunca acessasse vetores fora dos limites, não teria que se preocupar com overflow") e é perfeitamente possível que a linguagem ou sistema te protejam dessas vulnerabilidades. Por exemplo, se usássemos um tipos de dados separados para HTML e strings provenientes do usuário não seria possível tratar valores do usuário como HTML. A única maneira de passar uma string para o documento HTML é primeiro passá-la pela função de escape.  Similarmente, é possível evitar injeção de SQL se o tipo de dados usado para descrever comandos SQL não suportar a operação de concatenação.

---

Quanto às vulnerabilidades de Java ou Flash no browser, o principal problema é que esses sistemas são grandes e inevitavelmente conterão bugs, que virão à tona quando esses sistemas tiverem de lidar com entradas hostis de usuários maliciosos na internet. Por exemplo, algumas versões do plugin flash (implementado em C++) davam um stack overflow quando tentavam ler certos arquivos swf corrompidos e algumas versões da JVM permitiam que applets maliciosas escalassem seus privilágios e escapassem do sandbox seguro.